# Вывод строк с учетом количества повторений

Tags: mysql

Как вывести сначала те строки, которые чаще всего повторяются? Строка должна быть одна на `id_product` (`DISTINCT`)

```
id|id_product|
1 |    1     |
2 |    2     |
3 |    3     |
4 |    3     |
5 |    4     |
6 |    4     |
7 |    4     |
8 |    4     |
9 |    5     |
```

Должно получиться так:

```
id|id_product|
5 |    4     |
4 |    3     |
9 |    5     |
2 |    2     |
1 |    1     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что в результате должно быть `3 | 3`, а не `4 | 3` (то есть минимальный `id` для данного `id_product`), то тогда можно сгруппировать строки по `id_product` и отсортировать по их количеству (и дополнительно по id при равном количестве):

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS 'id', id_product FROM Test
GROUP BY id_product
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, id DESC
```